# All data from database is deleted when closing the application

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

What is the proper way to create a local-database file and then connect the app to it ? I want it to work even if you change the location of the project folder.

Right know what I do is: Project -> Add new item -> Service-based Database and I create one and then I go to Data -> Add new Data Source, I add the created database and I get the connection string.

Ok, all good, I can connect to it as I wish BUT all my data is erased from the database when I close the application (not always).

For example, this code:

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");           
c.Open();
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Persons (id int primary key, nume char(20), age int)");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (@id, @name, @age)", c);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Catalin");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", 20);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I run it first time to create the table and add an item to it and then, then if I run it the second time without the sqlcommand to create the table persons, it tells me that there is no Persons object, BUT if I run the second time the project with the same code, it tells me that there is already a Persons object...

I am using Visual C# Express Edition 2010.

Comment: Do you run your program by clicking on "Start debugging" and does your .mdf is in the Bin folder? If yes, maybe be your .mdf is overwritten each time you build/run your program.

Comment: [marc_s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36245969/447156) is quite correct. Also I suggest to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically and it would be better to use `Add` method with specify parameter type and it's size instead of `AddWithValue` since [it _might_ generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 8):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: I like the solution you gave me but unfortunately I can't use anything but Visual Studio (I am preparing for a contest and I am not allowed to install anything else but Visual Studio). Is there a way I can create a mdf file, place it somewhere in the project folder and then connect to it by knowing the location in the project folder? That would be perfect

Comment: @CatalinHoha: if you're using a `.mdf` file, you **must have** installed SQL Server, too - Visual Studio alone cannot work with `.mdf` files.

Answer (score 5):

Change the *Copy to output directory* setting from **Copy always** to **Copy if newer** in the property page for your database files. Every time you run the application the new database file is copied from your project to the `bin` folder, so all of your datas from the previous run are removed.

More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a pretty simple answer but maybe it's not the best use to do it this way.
Anyway, I add the database to the project and then I connect directly to it by doing so:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory)));
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""" + path + @"Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

This way, if you move your project between multiple PCs, the connection will still work (I needed this the most).
This also works with .SDF files and it's easier too.